# Writing nested if else into ternary operator

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have nested if else statement, is there any solution for turning this into ternary operator ?

```
let widthStyledMeter;
if (direction === 'horizontal') {
    if(size === "full"){
      widthStyledMeter = '100%';
    }else{
      widthStyledMeter = length;
    }
  } else {
    if(size === "full"){
      widthStyledMeter = '100%';
    }else{
      widthStyledMeter = thickness;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You already have pretty much the  best solution. No need to make it worse.

Comment: Just because you could nest ternary operators doesn't mean you should: once nested beyond a single level they become extremely difficult to read/skim quickly. Your original solution already works way better.

Comment: I understand that, but wanted to know how to approach that particular solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this **is way less readable**, it would look like this:

```
const widthStyledMeter = size === "full" ? "100%" : (direction === 'horizontal' ? length : thickness);
```

You have a common value set here, wich is `size == "full" = "100%"`, since it's there's no condition on the else statement you can reduce it to avoid a `size = "full"` double check

[Edit]
A more readable way would be:

```
let widthStyledMeter;
if (size === "full") {
    widthStyledMeter = "100%";
} else {
    widthStyledMeter = direction === "horizontal" ? length : thickness ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can use a ternary operator:

```js
let 
  widthStyledMeter,
  direction = "vertical",
  size = "100%",
  length = 100,
  thickness = 20;

direction === "horizontal"
  ? (widthStyledMeter = size === "full" ? "100%" : length)
  : (widthStyledMeter = size === "full" ? "100%" : thickness);

console.log(widthStyledMeter);
```

Also, since you're sure when `size` is `"full"` then `widthStyledMeter` will always be `"100%"`, so its better to check `size` first and then `direction`.

```js
let 
  direction = "vertical",
  size = "100%",
  length = 100,
  thickness = 20,
  widthStyledMeter =
    size === "full" ? "100%" : direction === "horizontal" ? length : thickness;

console.log(widthStyledMeter);
```